# Looking for functions with PHP tokenizer

Tags: php, static-analysis

Right now, I have a script which uses PHP's tokenizer to look for certain functions within a PHP source code file.  The pattern I am currently looking for is:

T_STRING + T_WHITESPACE (optional) + "("

This seems to match all of my test cases so far except variable functions, which I am ignoring for the purposes of this question.

The obvious problem here is that this pattern produces a lot of false positives, like matching function definitions:

```
public function foo() {  // foo() should not be matched
```

My question is, *is there a more reliable/accurate method for looking at source code and plucking out all the function invocations?*  Maybe a better method than using the tokenizer at all?

**Edit:**

In particular, I'm looking to emulate the functionality of the `disable_functions` PHP directive *within a class file*.  So, if `exec()` should be disallowed, I'm trying to find any uses of that function within the analyzed file.  I do realize that variable functions make this terribly difficult, so I am detecting these and disallowing them as well.

Comment: If you're just looking for them, you can simplify this a bit by stripping all T_WHITESPACE and T_COMMENT sections beforehand. Then it also becomes easier to assert the preceding token isn't a T_FUNCTION/method declaration. You'll be missing `$func();` and other invocations still.

Comment: @mario: Thanks for the comment/whitespace stripping suggestion - that will be helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first run the tokenizer (available in PHP). Then you run a parser on top of the tokens. The parser needs to read the tokens and should be able to tell your what a specific token has been used for. It depends on the reliability of your parser how reliable the outcome is.

If your current parser (you have not shown any code) is not reliable enough, you need to write a better parser. That simple it is. Probably you're not doing much more than just tokenizing and then reading as it passes which just might not be enough.

Comment: I am just using the tokenizer and looking for the token pattern mentioned in the OP.  I'm not using a parser currently.

Comment: The tokens only are pretty limited. Mario made some suggestions in his comment about how you could write some rough parser for the tokens. But regardless what you do, you will create a parser that is making use of the PHP tokenizer. If you could add some more info to your question for what specifically you're looking (the places where functions are called I assume) it will attract others to answer your question because they did something similar before. Additionally take a look into the [PHP QA tools](http://phpqatools.org/), especially those related to static code analysis how they do that.

Comment: I clarified my question a bit.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Wow, plus one for what you're aiming for. You'll need to do this strict and proper so it's not able to circumvent. +1 for your efforts so far, hope that you see some traction here and your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the tokenizer, consider instead using a higher-level parser to analyze your code. For example, [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) can explicitly identify function declarations, as well as variable function calls.